# How to stop page reload on button click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using this below code for button click event using jQuery. When button is clicked the page reloads.

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
    //Code goes here
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Is there some code explicitly added for reloading the page inside your function on button click? As far as I know, on a simple button click, a page doesn't reload.

Comment: Nothing I have added in the page

Comment: Only added jquery.min.js 1.11.3 and my code.

Comment: I am asking what code goes inside your function?

Comment: The above code. Now it is working.

Comment: I have created a span and appending it to a div.

Answer (score 43):

If your "button" is a `button` element, make sure you explicity set the `type` attribute, otherwise the WebForm will treat it as submit by default.

```
<button id="button1" type="button">Go</button>
```

If it's an `input` element, do so with jQuery with the following:

```
$('#button1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Code goes here
});
```

Read more: [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the answer. I am a rookie and your first statement clarified my mind. Thanks

Comment: what about for a tag? href will refresh the page

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the default event (click) from occurring.

```
$('#button1').click(function(e) {
    // prevent click action
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code here
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Is the same thing will apply for textbox on enter keypress?

Comment: It should, whatever event is fired it prevents the default action.