# Jquery unexpected result in ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm working with VS 2017 C# webforms app and have the following code:

This simple code tries to change the background of TextBoxes to yellow.

After I click on the button, the background of textboxes briefly Does change to yellow but then immediately reset back to white.

I noticed that conversion to white happen after the page_load event is called for the second time. I need your feedback on how this 2nd-page load affects jQuery and how to resolve the above issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="JQuery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script>
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("#g").click(function () {
                alert("test");
                $(".small,.big").css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        });

    </script>

    <style>
        .small
        {
            font-style:italic;
        }

         .big
        {
            font-style:italic;
        }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"  CssClass="big">ABC</asp:TextBox>        
            <br />
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" Font-Bold="true" CssClass="small big" >ABC</asp:TextBox>
            <br />
              <input type="text" class="big"   value="lll"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="g" Text="click" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "second page load"?  Any time a page load happens, any inline styling you had put on the previous elements is destroyed, as the load replaces every thing.

Comment: When program run page loads. After the button is clicked page load is fired for the 2nd time.

Comment: If you want the class change to persist between postbacks you would need to manage the class change from the code behind.

Comment: Right, so any inline styling would be destroyed, unless you re-run your script logic that sets it back.

Comment: OK thanks. So you guys suggesting I use a method like RegisterClientScriptBlock from code behind?

Comment: You could. Or you could change the styles from the code behind: `yourElement.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "yellow");`

Comment: Also, one thing I have a hard time to understand. Per Jquery only when the document is loaded and the button is clicked Jquery should apply CSS.  So why this is not happening in this case.

Comment: The JavaScript runs _before_ the page reloads. Once it has reloaded you are back to the initial state.

Comment: Ok. So i was wrong thinknig $(docmuent).ready also means page load is done

Comment: It does. But all you are doing in doc.ready is binding a JavaScript event listener. This will not make the event fire.

Comment: If you do not need the page to post back (ie. your code behind does not need to know that the button has been clicked), you could prevent the post back from happening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465557/how-to-stop-page-reload-on-button-click-jquery

Comment: Nice! this is probably what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I provide info on the behavior defined in the question here for the future reference.

Question was why Textbox briefly changes color and then turns white again.

Reason: When user click on the button(ASP button). document ready function get fired and click event get fired which validates the textbox and changes color.

But since we have an ASP button this causes a post back which again fires document ready event, but clearly, this time click event is not fired and therefore validation is not done.

If you need to work with ASP button you can enforce the validation from code behind(as explianed by the experts in this question comments) or in my case, I just moved the Juquery code before the end tag of the body,`</body>`(old fastioned javascript way) and it worked.

It was good if EnableViewstate property of textbox could preserve the CSS background color, but obviously, it does not.