# Can't update inner HTML with JQuery, it turns back immediately

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been trying to make this very simple feature work where the user clicks the submit button and the question number is updated.

On the browser when I click the button the question number becomes "2" for a second and turns back to "1" immediately. There is no console warnings or errors.

I tried it on the JSFiddle as well and when the button is pressed it gave me a 404 error code.

Here is the very small script and HTML that I am trying to run and also the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3dfmbzw/1/):

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  var level = 1;
  $('button').click(() => {
    level++;
    $("#question").text("Question " + level);
  });
});
```

```
  <h1 id="question">Question 1</h1>
  <form>
    <h3>What is your name?</h3>
    <textarea type="text" name="answer" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: assign a class or id to your submit button and then use it in .click  method

Comment: `return false` from your click event / change button to `type=button` / call e.stopPropagation in click event / remove the `form` completely - your form is POSTing so your page reloads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop page reload on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33465621/2181514)

Comment: just add `e.preventDefault();` to click event and you are good, another note you should be using `submit` event instead.

Comment: @ROOT depends on what the button does - in this case, no it should not be on submit event (IMO, as code is presented).  But agree with `e.preventDefault`.

Comment: @freedomn-m the first one did, thank you. I just had to change the type of button "submit" to "button". I tried removing the type before but apparently it acted as a submit button defaultly.

Comment: Yes, the default type is 'submit' so you have to specify 'type=button' explicitly

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The default type of button is submit even if you have not written but you also have specified it.

So what happens to your code :

Your function executes, we see the result and it reload as the type='submit' behaviour.

Make it type='button' not removing the type attribute.

And another thing i can see is you dont need to call $(document).ready() because it is not a function which is needed as the html loads.

Comment: *"you dont need to call $(document).ready()"* - If the JavaScript is placed before the HTML than using the `.ready()` event is indeed necessary, otherwise the click handler won't bind to the button element (since it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Agree with you, he can do the evaluation of the case based on his needs, just advised him to not use something if  is not nessesary

Comment: Generally better to advise to use doc.ready if it's not "needed".  Especially on SO where we only see a snippet/sample of the code.  There are too many questions that are basically "my click event doesn't fire" / "put it in doc.ready" / "that fixed it".  So better to err on the side of caution with doc.ready than suggest to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Because the page is reloading when you submit the form.

The default submit action for a `<form>` is the current URL when not otherwise specified.  And the default type for a `<button>` within a `<form>` is `submit` when not otherwise specified.  Though in this case you are explicitly specifying `type="submit"`.  So essentially your markup is explicitly indicating that you want to reload the page when clicking the button.

Since you're not intending to post a form, you can simplify the HTML and remove the `<form>` elements and make the button no longer a `submit` button:

```
<h1 id="question">Question 1</h1>
<h3>What is your name?</h3>
<textarea type="text" name="answer" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

If for some other reason you want/need to keep the `<form>` (styling perhaps?  though since it's not semantically a "form" then I'd recommend using something else, like a `<div>`) then you can at least specify `type="button"` to prevent default submit behavior:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="button" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: A button with no type attribute acts as type="submit", and will attempt to submit form data when clicked.

Comment: @FloriBruci: Submit what form?  The suggestion here is to remove the form.