# Jquery call to controller method reloads the page and does nothing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery call in my view which hits the controller method and data that returns from controller method needs to be shown in the view itself without reloading the page, controller method is being called but the problem is the page is getting reloaded and data is not being displayed.

Jquery code:

```
$(".submit").click(function () {
            var url = "/Home/GetData"

            //selected values from a dropdowns
            var type= $('#ddltypes :selected').text();
            var name = $('#ddlNames :selected').text();

            $.getJSON(url, { name : name , type: type}, function (data) {
                alert(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    console.log(data[i].ID);
                    $("ol").append('<li>' + data[i].ID + '</li>');
                }
            });
        });
```

```
<ol>

</ol>
```

Controller Method

```
public JsonResult GetData(string name, string type)
{
var data = dBLayer.GetMappings(name, type)

return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: Please include your html, is `.submit` inside a form? You need to do prevent default.

Comment: Asked *literaly* ten minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935912/cant-update-inner-html-with-jquery-it-turns-back-immediately

Comment: return false from your click event / change button to type=button / call e.preventDefault 
 / e.stopPropagation in click event / remove the form completely - your form is POSTing so your page reloads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop page reload on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465557/how-to-stop-page-reload-on-button-click-jquery/33465621#33465621)

Comment: submit button is  inside a form

Comment: Yes, your submit button is submitting the form - that's what's causing *"page is getting reloaded and data is not being displayed"*

Comment: Thanks, changing the button type from submit to button worked