# maintaining a change to the css for a user session. I have a jQuery that hides a block, but as the page refreshes the block reappears

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How to maintain a change to the css for a user session. I have a jQuery that hides a block, but as the page refreshes the block reappears.

```
jQuery('.ub-button-block-main').on('click',function() {
    alert("hello");
    jQuery('div#myDiv').css('display','none');  
})
```

Comment: Does the show/hide state apply globally to all posts that have this block? Or is state local to each individual post? In any case, it looks like you will need to persist this state server-side for the duration of the user session. If state is global you could use [cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). If it is local you could use a combination of cookies, the [WordPress data module](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-core-data/) and [post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/).

Comment: Found the answer... https://stackoverflow.com/q/33465557/1361676
Thanks Goran Mottram.

Comment: You’d probably need to use cookies to persist session changes that are reset on a page refresh, unless there is a stored value that can be retrieved to assert in some logic for that specific event. When the page is refreshed, the DOM is refreshed and unless you are checking for some stored value to either do or don’t do (if/else) something, those elements are  going to go back to their original state. 

I suggest you archive/remove this question if you have found your answer some other place. just saying…